# Server-sent events and php - how to be a proxy

Tags: php, proxy, server-sent-events

I have an endpoint which generates serversent events and I used to read it in my client. But recently they enforced the same-origin policy and I get the error `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Is there a way to read these server sent events in a php proxy and echo it in my own event service stream?

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the endpoint? To make it generate the required header?

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

Alternatively a "php proxy" could work, you can use CURL to load the remote data, then echo it back out adding the header as above.

Be aware that allowing all origins isn't a good idea, and you should instead send a list of trusted domains.

Comment: No I dont own the server-sent events . Its a different domain. I want to know how to proxy

Comment: Well as above, you create a proxy script and add that header. In short:
`$endpoint = file_get_contents("https://endpoint.url");`

`header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');`

`echo $endpoint;`

It'd be best to use curl though for loading remote data, you can have more control and better error handling etc.